# Calling main thread in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling method in separate thread. After sometime or after some event occurs I want to call main threads method. I am using C# in asp.net website.

To call separate thread i am using below code

```
 Thread thread       = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadMethod));
 thread.Start();
```

From threadMethod how to call main method?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of "main thread" are you envisaging in ASP.NET? Different requests are handled by different threads.

Comment: What are you doing in this separate thread? Just wondering what kind of work you're delegating to it considering you're doing it in ASP.NET

Comment: Each time I read someone is using threads withing asp.net I get the chill. Why on earth do you need to start threads by your own? This can cause some serious troubles...

Comment: I am sending HTTP request and waiting for response. But before sending request I want to display loading image. But If I call HTTP request in main thread then loading image will not display. If thread is not required here, then is there any event that I can use so that after displaying loading image I can send request(Like Doevents of VB)

Comment: The http request is sent on an asp.net page?

Comment: Ya I have one API. I want send request and then Response I have to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use threads, use ASP.NET Asynchronous operations.

That way you have a event handler fired when operation ends and you can update the page.